# Google Cloud Function + Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Jumping right to it...

I have the following python code in a Google Cloud Function

main.py

```
import flask, requests

def gce_test(request):
  test = {"data": {}, "meta": {}, "error": {}}

  metadata_server = "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/"
  metadata_flavor = {'Metadata-Flavor' : 'Google'}

  gce_id = requests.get(metadata_server + 'id', headers = metadata_flavor).text
  gce_name = requests.get(metadata_server + 'hostname', headers = metadata_flavor).text
  gce_machine_type = requests.get(metadata_server + 'machine-type', headers = metadata_flavor).text

  test["data"]["gce_id"] = gce_id
  test["data"]["gce_name"] = gce_name
  test["data"]["gce_machine_type"] = gce_machine_type

  test["meta"]["metadata_server"] = metadata_server
  test["meta"]["metadata_flavor"] = metadata_flavor
  test["meta"]["metadata_server_full"] = metadata_server + 'id'

  test["meta"]['generator'] = 'google-cloud-function'

  return flask.jsonify(test)
```

The problem that I am facing is I get a `404 page not found` for **gce_id**, **gce_machine_type**, **gce_name** which means the request to the **metadata_server** is not being made...

My question is how do I make a HTTP Get request to the **metadata_server** and pass it the instance name as a param...is that doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently making requests to the GCE metadata server URL. Cloud Functions run on top of GAE Standard, and as such end up using the [http://metadata.google.internal](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata#identifying_which_metadata_endpoint_to_use) url. I've provided an example that works with the current cloud function to log the project id.

```
import flask, requests

def gce_test(request):
  test = {"data": {}, "meta": {}, "error": {}}

  metadata_server = "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id"
  metadata_flavor = {'Metadata-Flavor' : 'Google'}


  project = requests.get(metadata_server, headers = metadata_flavor).text
  test["data"]["gce_id"] = project
  return flask.jsonify(test)
```